# Make a custom CSV List of files with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to make a CSV file with a list of files that I would use to make a .cpk file with another program.

The list in the CSV should contain only files that are in the Output folder:

```
    <root folder>
     makecsv.ps1
        Output (the files)
```

The CSV formatting of the CSV is simple:

```
    "<full path to file>", "<relative path>", <line number, starting with 0>, Uncompress
```

An example of the output would be:

```
    "F:/Aemulus/Output/battle/cutin/bct_p_bc0004.dds", "/battle/cutin/bct_p_bc0004.dds", 0, Uncompress
    "F:/Aemulus/Output/sound/motionse/em0000.dat", "/sound/motionse/em0000.dat", 1, Uncompress
    "F:/Aemulus/Output/script/field/fscr0150_002_100.bf", "/script/field/fscr0150_002_100.bf", 2, Uncompress
```

I would write a program for this, but there's a private reason on why I need to have a Powershell script for this, and while I *can* output simple csv files, I have absolutely no idea on how I should approach *this*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. But I strongly recommend you look up the commands and their parameters in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/), so you understand how this code works. Also, feel encouraged to ask as many questions about it as you need to understand it.

```
# the "script:" scope prefex is required, so we can change the value later
$script:lineNumber = 0

# get the full path of the folder, so we can use it to build the relative path later
$rootPath = Resolve-Path -Path "Output"

# get all files in folder and subfolers
# then build the desired output using "calculated properties"
# and finally export to csv file
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -File -Recurse | Select-Object -Property @{
    Name = "FullPath"
    Expression = "FullName"
}, @{
    Name = "RelativePath"
    Expression = { $_.FullName.Replace($rootPath, "")}
}, @{
    Name = "LineNumber"
    Expression = {($script:lineNumber++)}
}, @{
    Name = "Uncompress"
    Expression = {"Uncompress"}
} | Export-Csv -Path "export.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","
```